# Should "time" be capitalized?

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns, poetic-devices

I would like to request some clarification on the capitalization of the word *time*. Is it possible in certain contexts to use it not as a common noun, but as a proper noun?

For example, what if you are using the word as if it were its own entity, for example: "Time ruled"?

Comment: The concept of time could be time ruled. Doesn't make it a proper noun.

Comment: Well, if there were an Egyptian king named "Time", that would be capitalized.

Comment: It's probably justifiable under the utilisation of the concept of anthropomorphism.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your example is getting at. Could you add additional context? In poetry & fiction it is not uncommon for writers to capitalize things like Death, Love, Truth, and Time, though it's somewhat archaic. Emily Dickinson, for instance, capitalizes all sorts of words that aren't usually capitalized (see her poem "Because I could not stop for Death"). There aren't hard and fast rules for these things in creative writing, but in formal writing I would leave it uncapitalized unless I was using it as an item in a bulleted list or the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Capitalize it or not, as you please. There are no Rules for Significant Capitalization. It's always a matter of individual (or editorial) judgement. [The Academy](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) hasn't gotten around to capitals yet.

Comment: The only relevant rule here is that proper names are capitalised. Whether one will treat something  as a proper name depends on how what it stands for is conceptualised in the given context.

Comment: @jsw29 Some names are decreed to be spelled with lower-case initial letters. But can they then be said to have converted to common nouns? 'The works of Robert Burns and e e cummings were on the first week's agenda.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, decreed by whom? The fact that somebody may demand that his name be spelled in a nonstandard way, as an attention-getting device, does not mean that the rest of us have to accede to such self-serving demands. Coca-Cola may, for marketing reasons, print its name in a particular script and a particular colour, but surely the rest of us are under no obligation to go along with that; the same applies to Edward Estlin Cummings.

Comment: @jsw29 I believe someone was taken to court by Biro when they lower-cased in print in imitation of now common genericisations such as sandwich, hoover, google. But are you telling me that you don't use the formatting << i-Pad >>? // In any case [dreadful accidental pun], the usage << e e cummings >> is still available and recognised as acceptable. There seems a flaw in the blanket claim 'proper names are capitalised.' Here, one isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider "time" a proper noun if you consider it to represent the name of something. Presumably you would be personifying the concept of "time". ("[Father Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_Time)", for example, is a well-known personification.) Whether it would be a good idea to do so or not is probably more of a matter for [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) than for EL&U.

Besides personification, the English language has another tradition of capitalizing common nouns. This practice was once quite widespread (and has been retained in German, for example). This usage gradually became more restricted (as seen in [the U.S. Declaration of Independence](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration-transcript)) and is almost entirely gone from modern English. Your writing might therefore seem a bit old-fashioned if you capitalize such words but don't make clear that your are personifying (and perhaps even if you do).

Comment: One may also argue that *Time* could be treated as a proper name, even if no personification is involved, in so far as there is only one Time (in the sense of the all-encompassing temporal framework). This would be analogous to *Universe* and *Internet* sometimes being treated as proper names. It would, however, be unwise to do so unless the context provides some strong motivation for it.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, thank you. And in an astronomy / physics context, "space" / "Space" would be analogous, though again lower case is far more common.